# How can i add consecutives elements in a list composed of the consecutive value of the previous element and a zero in the second term?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, list, dataframe

I would like to create a new list that takes my existing list L by adding **the consecutive value of the previous element** (first term) and a **zero in the second term** for an entire list.

Input:

```
L = [(1, 12), (3, 14), (6, 19), ..., (7412, 15), (7415, 15)]
```

I would like this output :

```
L = [(1, 12), (2, 0) ,(3, 14), (4, 0), (5, 0), (6, 19), ... , (7412, 15), (7413, 0), (7414, 0), (7415, 15)]
```

Comment: So just insert the zeroes as you iterate through the list? Go ahead and do it. We don't write the code for you, but post what you've done and maybe we can spot an error. I'd probably write a function that returns a completely new list.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the job. Not the most readable, though.

```
L = [(1, 12), (3, 14), (6, 19)]
keys = {key[0]:idx for (idx, key) in enumerate(L)}
[(x, L[keys[x]][1]) if x in keys.keys() else (x, 0) for x in range(1, L[-1][0] + 1)]
```

Output:

```
[(1, 12), (2, 0), (3, 14), (4, 0), (5, 0), (6, 19)]
```

Instead of list-comprehension simple for-loops could be used to make it a bit more readable, but also take up more lines of code.